# Let's burn(inate) our [finance]!

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

The [financial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/financial) and [finance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/finance) tags are meta-tags and should be burninated.

The tag wiki for [financial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/financial) says:

> Anything related to financial calculations and processing of financial data. For example, this tag can be used for questions about interest rates calculations, stock exchange data processing, market data analysis, etc.

The tag wiki for [finance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/finance) is much more extensive, here is an excerpt:

> The finance (or "financial services") industry is an umbrella term for organisations that manage money & assets. It includes businesses like banks, credit card companies, insurance companies, consumer finance companies, stock brokerages, hedge funds and investment funds and some government sponsored enterprises.

Let's look at the [four criteria for burnination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/168333):

**Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

The term "financial" can apply to a lot of things. Sometimes a broad coverage is dealt with by a good tag wiki, but in this case that is not true. The tag wiki itself says it can be about anything from interest rate calculations to market data analysis.

The tag wiki for [finance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/finance) says that it is "for problems specific to the finance industry", followed by no less than 7 different examples, from financial messaging protocols to market data analysis. It also points out that "finance industry" is an umbrella term, so a very large variety of questions could be tagged with "finance".

**Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

Arguably yes, as a lot of software is written for the finance industry. However, at the technical level, this is mostly irrelevant. Programming questions about these should be tagged with the more specific technical issues they address. For example, a question about the SWIFT messages should be tagged with [swift-mt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift-mt). That will make it much better searchable than the generic terms "finance" or "financial".

**Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

No. As pointed out above, the tags are too broad.

**Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

Arguably, yes. On Stock Ov... sorry, Stack Overflow, "financial" still means "some code or calculation that involves money". And the tag wiki for "finance" gives many examples of what the tag should be applied to. Unfortunately, that guidance can be summarized as "any problem you could encounter while writing software for the finance industry". Which makes it a poor tool for classification, precisely because a lot of software is written for that industry. So the clear meaning does not save it.

To summarize: these two tags are meta-tags, and too broad to be useful for Stack Overflow. Let's burninate them.

Comment: I misread it as *Let's burn our fiance* :-(

Comment: @BhargavRao The tag "fiancé(e)" does not require burnination. [It is a valid tag on MSO and MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105045/how-to-stop-my-husband-from-answering-your-questions). :-)

Comment: "At a more technical level, this is irrelevant" - have you ever written software for the financial industry? You'll find it to be, at times, very different on a technical level. The standards and methods that are legally enforced are different than your typical shop, and it is not uncommon for this to creep into the areas that are on-topic for SO. I'm not saying the tag isn't in need of review, but you should reconsider a burnination request.

Comment: @corsiKa I have, although I have not run in the type of situation you describe. I imagine there are situations like number precision, or legal standards? I believe these were better handled with more specific tags.

Comment: I take it that this post is _only_ about burninating `[finance]`?  I just noticed that http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191 says "**DO NOT** try for a two-fer - one tag per discussion."  `[financial]` and `[finance]` are two different tags.

Comment: In my opinion there are not enough arguments to say whether or not it's useful or not. True, it's a meta-tag, but that isn't really bad either to create some context. Perhaps there are specific solutions in that industry that make no sense outside of it, though I must mention that I have no experience in that industry. While I know that the amount of followers isn't the best indication to see if a tag is on-topic, it seems they have a reasonable amount of followers (at least finance is), to me that looks like they could be useful. I agree to make them synonyms/merge them though.

Comment: @RexKerr Well, shame on me... I missed that. I do believe the two should be synonyms though.

Answer (score 9):

The tags have under 10,000 entries each, and from a quick glance they contain a lot of specialized requests that aren't necessarily about some subtopic like swift-mt.  Splitting up this way will leave each tag without a critical mass to do any good.  Maybe they should be **merged**, but unless there's strong evidence that nobody really cares about these tags (e.g. very small numbers for favorites) it doesn't seem as meta- as a lot of other tags that could be argued are meta-ish (e.g. performance, algorithm, sql, etc.).

Comment: For reference, check out the new [burnination process](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/SOCVR-RoomInformation/blob/master/burnination.md). Also, a tag not being as bad as other tags on the site is not a reason to not burninate the tag. If the tag is bad, it fits the criteria for burnination, and removing it will do more good than harm, it should be burninated, regardless of the other tags on the site.

Comment: @tiny You and your chat-room buddies keep plugging this process you've worked up supposedly in reference to Shog9's answer, but you keep ignoring the parts of his answer where he says, *"If the tag isn't actively causing harm, leave it be."* And from [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239190/239191#239191): *"If you're thinking that it's not worth the effort for tags that generally don't seem to be causing any problems, then you're sharper than half the folks throwing up these requests. If it looks like pointless busywork, it probably is pointless busywork..."*

Comment: So, it seems to me that burnination requests need to *at minimum* provide some explanation for how the tag is causing harm, not just pointing out that a tag is ambiguous and/or containing a bunch of veiled jokes about how no one can be an expert in finance. Of course, they can. It is a perfectly valid way of categorizing questions. Most tags are "too broad," like [windows], [android], and [java]. Let's not burninate those. I can't shake the feeling that people are bent on turning this into a witchhunt. Of all the *serious* problems on SO, a few "broad" tags are not among them.

Comment: @CodyGray I wasn't commenting on this specific case, I'm not sure what I think about that yet. I was merely providing reference to the current process, and saying that the points provided in this answer aren't valid arguments *against* burnination.

Comment: @TinyGiant - Seems to be serving a purpose, not causing harm.  That was my point.  And I was arguing _against_ the claim "does not add any meaningful information".  So I disagree with the idea to burninate _both_.  Merging seems reasonable; that something is "finance" instead of "financial" does not give very much information (for example).

Comment: @CodyGray Tiny and his chat-room buddies are truly sorry for having put up and making happen a serious process to regulate burninate requests, based on the official guidance. It is our bad... I'll put it this way: if you disagree with the burninate request, downvote the post, no need to leave snarky and disrespectful comments behind. Better yet, _write an answer_. Thanks.

Comment: @Tunaki - But I did downvote the post, and wrote an answer, and was told, "You don't understand the process."  And the process is based on guidance, and Cody Gray pointed out part of the guidance that seemed to indicate that my reply was even more on target than I had thought.  I don't think that's irrelevant.  (Point could be made without snarky comments, but **not** just by downvoting the original post.)

Comment: @tunaki I did all of those things, thank you. And I left a snarky comment because I was disagreeing with Tiny Giant's comment. Expressing disagreement with a comment is a perfectly valid reason to leave a comment, not an answer. Notice that I was pointing out how you have glossed over an important part of the "official guidance" that you are hiding behind. And if you think my comment was disrespectful, then we'll have to agree to disagree. The only thing mildly snarky was the use of the phrase "chat-room buddies," but that seems to be exactly what it is, the defense of his buddy coming on cue.

Comment: @RexKerr Please read the first comment again. It doesn't say "You don't understand the process". It says "For reference, ...", which means it's an additional pointer to something, a side-note if you want. Then it goes with "Also, ...", and at no point is there a reference in the current process that you were doing something wrong. In fact, your wrote a real answer and kudos to you and no-one is disagreeing with that.

Comment: @CodyGray Disagreement can be expressed without the use of snarky comments and expressions like "you and your buddies", which, yes, I find disrespectful. And no, you didn't do all those things. If you want to _improve_ the current process, feel free to drop by our [SOCVR](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) chat room and make suggestions. We are all ears and we could certainly make use of them.

Comment: @Tunaki - The literal content doesn't say that, but that's the implication.  (Implication is important, no?  Otherwise "chat-room buddies" is merely an irrelevant verbal flourish.)  It may even be true--I haven't been following the burnination process very closely, and assumed that standard reasoning applies when evaluating the listed criteria.  (Partial ordering, for instance: if X scores better on various criteria than Y, and Y is okay, X is also okay.) But if true, discounting snarkiness, Cody's comment was relevant; and if not, the implication was unneeded; and it's being argued both ways.

Comment: Ugh, now I'm defending snarkiness on Meta? It is *Meta*. Sorry you got your feelings hurt when you, ironically, showed up to defend your buddy. But let's not miss the point. Burninating tags that are not causing a problem is not only a waste of time and energy, but I'd argue actively harmful. Shog9 has already made this point, and the burnination-advocates (is that a better, more neutral term?) continually ignore it. I'm so tired of shilling for burnination of tags just because their meanings seem ambiguous. BTW I don't want to chat, thx for the invitation newayz.