# Are we [trading] one problem for another?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

I came across this [trading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/trading) tag. The tag excerpt says,

> The act of buying and selling financial instruments, such as money markets spot instruments, stocks, bonds, commodities, virtual currencies, indices, futures, options, CFD-s and other derivatives, performed on a for-profit basis.

and the [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/trading/info) states:

> **Trading** in general and **speculative trading** are a form of participation in a process of mutually beneficial exchange.
>
> **`Speculative trading`** is a knowingly speculative, for-profit, participation in a multi-layer scene of sell-side and buy-side market
> participants ( liquidity providers ), brokerage entities / mediators,
> market regulators ( where territorially applicable and  legally
> enforced ) and retail traders.
>
> Markets typically offer trading in both Buy ( a.k.a. Long ) and Sell (
> Short ) contract positions for various financial instruments such as:
>
> - money markets spot contracts,
> - ETF contracts,
> - virtual currencies,
> - stocks,
> - bonds,
> - commodities,
> - indices,
> - futures,
> - options,
> - options on index,
> - non-deliverable swaps,
> - CFD-s and other derivatives.

I do not understand how this is related to programming. This seems to be more about finance than programming.

Let's go through the [**burnination criteria**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324071/8387076):

> 1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

Keeping in mind that I do not have much knowledge in this specific field, I believe the tag does *not* describe the contents of the questions. Say, for the sake of argument, if I have a question that is tagged only [trading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/trading), I do not understand (without reading the question) which programming language/API the question is about. So, in a sense, it is ambiguous too.

> 2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

No, not at all. If a question is regarding any particular API that helps in trading, then the tag for that should be used. Stack Overflow does not deal in finances.

> 3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

I don't think so. Same reason as in #1 above.

> 4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

Somewhat yes, because if we have two APIs that are used in some trading, then the tag may tell that the question is about a trading API, but not exactly which one.

In this particular case, I believe the main problem is that the tag is completely off-topic for the site. The rest is up to the community to decide whether the tag should be deleted or not.

Comment: Adding context, based on [the currently visible oldest question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/59327/1), the tag has existed since 2008.

Comment: wau, the tag info was edited the last time 2016 there is still traffoc with that tag and questions and answers are upvoted and accepted, looks like a normal tag, which frequently used

Comment: it's more a "topic" tag than a language/library/language-thing tag. Kinda like [retail] or [ecommerce]

Comment: "Snarky" comments from https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318316/lets-burninate-our-finance?rq=1 seem applicable to here as well. "So, in a sense, it is ambiguous too" is, in a sense, wrong. It's actually broad, not ambiguous. [trading] can deal with many languages, APIs, etc, but it refers to exactly what the tag's definition says it does. Someone might not be able to answer it, regardless of their language or API knowledge, without knowledge of the [trading] context -- this speaks directly to 3) and 4).

Answer (score 42):

Some programming questions requires expert knowledge in another knowledge field to be answered appropriately.  This is true for many advanced topics, like trading, [geographic information systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_information_system) (GIS), [bioinformatics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bioinformatics), and so many others.

Without this expert knowledge, questions could attract irrelevant answers from people not aware of the context in which these questions asked.

To give an example, I once was engaged in a lengthy discussion with a programmer who was insisting on representing cash flows with decimals instead of floating point numbers in a software computing risks. In bookkeeping applications decimals are of course the only sane choice (or integers), but for risk management using a lot of stochastic models and numerical approximations, floating-point numbers are the right choice.

Also, I guess you will nowadays not find a lot of people happy to use dbase2 outside of GIS users, etc.

We also have similar tags like [geography](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/geography), [math](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/math), [bioinformatics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bioinformatics), [medical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/medical) and probably many others.

Also, I do not really understand what is the urge to suppress a tag for a field, you say you have no experience about? If people in the field find it useful and there is no real problem with it (like most questions are low quality, most answers low quality, or spam, which is not your argumentation line), why bother at all?  You're just suggesting to ditch someone else's tool.

Comment: I'm an experts on economics and will tell you something: everyone and their mother uses the same arithmetic operations and models from every other field, but with fancier names.

Comment: @Braiam What are you trying to say? I do not even remotely get it.

Comment: In a software context, there's mission-critical and non-mission-critical software. There's no difference in how you write safety-related software for automotive, aerospace, medical or industrial purposes - sure there are lots of different standards, but they all boil down to the same technical safety measures in the end. You could even have a consumer household device with the same safety requirements as software designed for use in a nuclear power plant, because either application could injure a huge number of people in case it is safety-related.

Comment: My point being is that tags like medical and automotive probably don't make a whole lot of sense, there is the tag safety-critical which can be used for both. All of these are very low traffic tags though.

Comment: @MichaëlLeBarbier That I know anything in economics will not help me to answer any question at all better than those that known about the actual programming language.

Comment: @Braiam So your are saying something like “I totally disagree.” ?  Maybe you could support your point with arguments. :-)

Comment: Oh but I'm not _just_ disagreeing, I'm pointing out how ridiculous the position is from the get go.

Comment: Re *"dbase2"*: Don't you mean [DB2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_DB2)? [dBase II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBase) is from the early 1980s and dBase III was released in 1984.

Comment: @PeterMortensen I mean dBaseII, dbase files are used as compagnons to raw geographic file systems.  See p. 25  https://www.esri.com/content/dam/esrisites/sitecore-archive/Files/Pdfs/library/whitepapers/pdfs/shapefile.pdf

Of course modern software supports other formats but there is still a lot of data stored in this format and systems processing it out there, so despite its age iti s still widely used in some areas. IIRC I had to work with the dbaseII variant.

Comment: Regarding the last paragraph, when someone comes across a seemingly off-topic tag, I think it is important to trigger a [meta-tag:discussion] about it because these tags tend to attract poor quality / off-topic questions. On the other hand this answer does not cover anything specific about [tag:trading] and why it is useful to the site (note that I’m not saying it isn’t).

Comment: @DidierL You are very right! Also note, the question does not say anything either about the quality of questions & answers under the tag.

Answer (score 9):

When the tag is used in the wiki-intended context then it makes sense, as explained by this answer: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/415762/1690217 and I agree with the general premise:

> Some programming questions requires expert knowledge in another knowledge field to be answered appropriately. This is true for many advanced topics, like trading, geographic information systems, bioinformatics, and so many others.

But there is genuine ambiguity in posts where the concept of *trading* is assumed to mean general commerce or accounting, instead of specifically *Stock Market* analysis or interactions, as is inferred from this example post: [Javascript - Working on two dimensional arrays to calculate win/lose](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50610270/1690217)

[algorithmic-trading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/algorithmic-trading) is a specific tag that should be used for many posts tagged with [trading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/trading) and that might be a cleanup avenue. But for many general accounting questions the *trading* aspect is not conducive to finding a viable solution.

[pine-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pine-script) is highly linked (over 1/3 of all posts) and on review many posts are specifically relating to *pine-script* even though they are not tagged as such. In this case [trading] starts to become irrelevant what is important is that posters find experts in the *pine-script* community.

Ultimately the verb *Trading* is itself ambiguous on its own, there are many commodities that can be *traded*.

My sniff test is would I choose to put this tag on my *Ignore* list, even though I am not remotely interested or involved with stock markets/futures or even currency trading, I do not have the confidence that the tag is being used as explained in the tag wiki and I don't want to miss out on helping new posts where the user was not aware of the wiki specifics or how they may not be relevant to solving their post.

Comment: My personal sniff test is whenever the tag makes the question easier to find for the relevant expert. Most of these, it does not and can be safely removed.